# Strange issue with ">" and "<" being converted to "&lt;" and "&gt;" in javascript in my jsf app

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, facelets

I have some javascript that i'm trying to use in a jsf app. I've narrowed it down so that if I take out the lines below, things work fine, but when I have these lines in, I get an error in the chrome console which says "unexpected ;" and it shows the first line as `if(maxdays &gt; 1000) {`

Why is it converting the greater than symbol to `&gt;`?

```
if(maxdays > 1000) {
    maxdays = 1000;
}
```

EDIT:
Here's the entire JSF page.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">


<h:head>


    <title>Protocol Dashboard</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/highcharts.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    //var chartData;
                    //var goodData;
                    var chart;
                    var studyType;
                    var categories;
                    var maxdays;
                    //var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    var options = {

                        chart : {
                            renderTo : 'container',
                            type : 'bar'
                        },

                        title : {
                            text : 'Gantt module development plan'
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: studyType
                        },
                        xAxis : {
                            categories : [ 'Planning', 'Development',
                                    'Testing', 'Documentation' ]
                        },

                        yAxis : {
                            type : 'datetime',
                            min : Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
                            labels : {
                                formatter : function() {
                                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d/%Y',
                                            this.value);
                                }
                            }

                        },

                        tooltip : {
                            formatter : function() {
                                var point = this.point;
                                return '<b>'
                                        + point.category
                                        + '</b><br/>'
                                        + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y',
                                                point.low)
                                        + ' - '
                                        + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y',
                                                point.y);
                            }
                        },

                        series : [ {
                            data : [ {
                                low : Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
                                y : Date.UTC(2012, 0, 15)
                            }, {
                                low : Date.UTC(2012, 0, 10),
                                y : Date.UTC(2012, 4, 28)
                            }, {
                                low : Date.UTC(2012, 3, 15),
                                y : Date.UTC(2012, 4, 28)
                            }, {
                                low : Date.UTC(2012, 4, 15),
                                y : Date.UTC(2012, 4, 28)
                            } ]
                        }, {
                            data : [ {
                                low : Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
                                y : Date.UTC(2012, 1, 15)
                            }, {
                                low : Date.UTC(2012, 0, 10),
                                y : Date.UTC(2012, 3, 15)
                            }, {
                                low : Date.UTC(2012, 3, 15),
                                y : Date.UTC(2012, 6, 14)
                            }, {
                                low : Date.UTC(2012, 4, 15),
                                y : Date.UTC(2012, 4, 25)
                            } ]
                        } ]

                    };

                    function loadData() {

                        //options.series.length = 0;
                        //options.xAxis.categories.length = 0;

                        $('#hiddenData').val('09-034,99|10-053,194');
                        $('#hiddenCategories').val('09-034|10-053');
                        $('#clickedMenu').val('P2C');
                        $('#hiddenMaxDays').val('194');



                        var chartData = $('#hiddenData').val();
                        console.log('hiddenData = '+chartData);

                        categories = $('#hiddenCategories').val();
                        console.log('hiddenCategories = '+categories);

                        studyType = $('#clickedMenu').val();
                        console.log('clickedMenu = '+studyType);

                        maxdays = $('#hiddenMaxDays').val();
                        console.log('hiddenMaxDays = '+maxdays);
                        console.log('maxdays = '+maxdays);



                        //options.yAxis.max = maxdays;

                        options.subtitle.text = studyType;

                        var goodData = chartData.split('|');
                        //console.log('goodData = '+goodData);

                        //var goodCategories = categories.split(",");
                        //console.log('goodCategories = '+goodCategories);
                        /*
                        var series = {

                            data : []
                        };

                        var cat = {
                            categories : []
                        };

                        try {
                            $.each(goodData, function(index, value) {
                                var goodData2 = value.split(",");
                                //series.name = goodData2[0];
                                series.data.push(parseFloat(goodData2[1]));

                            });

                            $.each(goodCategories, function(index, value) {
                                var prot = value;
                                options.xAxis.categories.push(value);

                            });

                            options.series.push(series);
                            //console.log(options);
                        } catch (err) {
                            //console.log("ERROR ..." + err.description + '  message:'
                            //+ err.message);

                        }*/

                    }

                    function loadDataAndCreateChart() {
                        loadData();
                        //console.log(options);
                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                    }

                    loadDataAndCreateChart();

                });
    </script>

</h:head>
<h:body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <h:inputHidden value="#{selectCategory.jsonResults }" id="hiddenData" />
    <h:inputHidden value="#{selectCategory.jsonResultsCategories }" id="hiddenCategories" />
    <h:inputHidden value="#{selectCategory.menuItem}" id="clickedMenu" />
    <h:inputHidden value="#{selectCategory.maxDays}" id="hiddenMaxDays" />

</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should show the surrounding JSF code.  What's happening is that JSF is performing an HTML escape on the JavaScript text.

Comment: How do I make it not do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Facelets, which is a XML based view technology. JavaScript operators like `>`, `&`, etc are [special characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) in XML and are **illegal** when used for other purposes inside a XML file. Facelets is taking care of them this way.

I strongly recommend to put all that JS code in its own `.js` file and reference it by a `<script src>` or a [`<h:outputScript>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html).

E.g.

```xml
<script src="#{request.contextPath}/js/global.js"></script>
```

or

```xml
<h:outputScript name="js/global.js" />
```

Additional advantage is that you can finetune browser caching this way and end up in a more efficiently served website.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: please note how I referenced the libraries. You should prefer domain-relative paths over URI-relative paths. Using `../` is a maintenance pain. If you move the view or change the request URI, it'll break.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but this won't help when doing IE conditional comment. How would I prefent Facelets converting brackets for conditional comments?

Comment: @Buhake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574588/if-ie-doesnt-work-with-facelets/

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I did see it already. I am now using your OmniFaces library for this. It works like a charm. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`&gt;` is the HTML entity which must be used to output the `>` character in HTML. `<` and `>` are special characters used by the HTML markup and must thus be escaped to `&lt;` and `&gt;` if these characters must be displayed in the page. I suspect you're using a JSF tag which escapes its input.

I don't have much experience with JSF, but you might try to enclose the script in a CDATA section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
   your JavaScript code here
]]>
</script>
```

But the best solution is not to have JavaScript in HTML at all, and load it from an external file.

Comment: It's all inside the h:head tag

Comment: Your first attempt with the JS inside a HTML/XML comment makes no sense. It's just a leftover style of the 90's when not all browsers supported/understood JavaScript and thus failed to parse the `<script>`, such as Netscape 1.0 or something. None of those browsers should nowadays be in use anymore. I'm not sure about the CDATA solution though, but this is not as nice as just refactoring the JS bunch into its own `.js` file.

Comment: @BalusC: although I agree it isn't useful anymore, I've used this trick to make XHTML code validate against the w3c validator, though. So it still has its utility (although a CDATA section is probably cleaner nowadays)

Comment: This answer is correct, but its supposed to be commented like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
   your JavaScript code here
//]]>
</script>