# <!--[if IE]> conditional comments are rendered HTML-escaped in Facelets

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf, facelets, conditional-comments

I'm trying to use an IE conditional comment to declare a CSS resource:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="common.css" library="css" />
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{resource['css:ie.css']}" />   
<![endif]-->
```

However, that doesn't seem to work. I'm seeing this in my generated HTML output:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/context/faces/javax.faces.resource/common.css?ln=css" />        
<!--[if IE]&gt;
    &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/context/faces/javax.faces.resource/ie.css?ln=css&quot;/&gt;
&lt;![endif]-->
```

It works fine without the conditional comment. I'm not using the context parameter [`javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388109/how-can-i-remove-html-comments-in-my-facelets/3388169#3388169). How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is it there in the generated HTML? Open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*.

Comment: nope, and that's strange i can't find it in either IE or FireFox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This indeed won't work as Facelets implicitly HTML-escapes the comment's contents. Your best bet is to put it in a `<h:outputText escape="false">` as follows:

```html
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if IE]&gt;&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/#{resource['css:ie.css']}&quot; /&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />
```

This is however a line of ugliness. [The OmniFaces JSF utility library](http://omnifaces.org) has a [`<o:conditionalComment>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/conditionalComment) for exactly this purpose:

```
<o:conditionalComment if="IE">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{resource['css:ie.css']}" />   
</o:conditionalComment>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you are not really using the `library` attribute the right way. It should identify a common "theme", not the subfolder where the files are placed in, just put that subfolder in the `name` attribute instead. See also [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/common.css" />
<o:conditionalComment if="IE">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{resource['css/ie.css']}" />   
</o:conditionalComment>
```

Comment: the outputText solution worked very fine, still the param solution didn't work i don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest

```html
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if IE]&gt; " escape="false"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{request.contextPath}/faces/javax.faces.resource/ie.css?ln=css" />
<h:outputText value=" &lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false"/>
```

So you escape only small piece of code and #{request.contextPath} works as expected